# Call multiple Javascript functions from JSP in Spring

Tags: javascript, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I am developing a `Maven Spring` project in which I want to call multiple `javascript` functions from `JSP`. I am able to call all the functions without any issues but I would like to call them on different `div`.

Here is the code of `JSP`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var submit = '${submitVal}';  //Variables from controller
var accept = '${acceptVal}';
var reject = '${rejectVal}';

document.body.onload = function()
{
    drawBarChart(submit);
    drawBarChart(accept);
    drawBarChart(reject);
}
</script> 

<h1>Submit Chart</h1>
<div id='submit'></div>

<h1>Accept Chart </h1>
<div id='accept'></div>

<h1>Reject Chart</h1>
<div id='reject'></div>
```

`drawBarChart` is the name of my JS function and it displays bar chart. Right now it displays all the headings one below other first and then all 3 diagrams. I would like them to be displayed in the `div` so that the diagrams appears below respective headings.

Comment: How does `drawBarChart` currently locate where to put the charts? Does it use `document.getElementById("submit").innerHTML = ` for example?

Comment: Since this project is part of a huge project I dint write every code.. 
I am guessing document.body.onload just simply displays one below other
inside the body

Comment: No, `onload` just executes things when the page loads. It won't do anything for where the charts get put. If you inspect the source code when you are testing this, look for where it currently puts the charts in the HTML.

Comment: JavaScript is a programming language which has functions which can manipulate HTML, but as a whole is entirely separate from HTML. Its syntax doesn't describe its output; its statements do.

Comment: you were right..there was a div in JS where it was getting inserted. 
Thanks for the help

Comment: Awesome! Glad you figured it out. Happy coding!